# What sense does it make to upgrade Knisch's first skill?

Tags: hearthstone, hearthstone-mercenaries

I can not see any difference.

[image: Screenshot of upgrade]

Sorry for the German screenshot, but I do not know how to do `LC_ALL=C` in Windows. But even if you can not understand the description, you can see that there is no difference. Or maybe you can point me at the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the [speed](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Mercenaries/Ability#Speed).  The upgraded version has a lower speed (7) which means it can react faster.